# How to create multiple beans at runtime for different profiles in Spring Boot?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

In my project I have following properties files

```
application.properties
   spring.application.name=Profiles
   spring.profiles.active=dev,qa
   spring.message=Hello world from localhost environment

application-dev.yml
    server.port=9091

application-qa.yml
   server.port=9091
```

And below Java classes

```
ProfileConfig.java

@Profile({"dev", "qa"})
@Configuration
public class ProfileConfig {

    @Autowired
    private Environment environment;

    private static Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ProfileConfig.class);
@Bean
    public void config() {
        System.out.println("****************SERVER.PORT " + environment.getProperty("server.port"));
        LOGGER.info("Succesfully loaded the environment.");
    }
}

SpringbootProfiles.java

  @SpringBootApplication
public class Springbootprofiles {

    private static Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Springbootprofiles.class);
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Springbootprofiles.class, args);
        LOGGER.info("Springboot profiles application is running successfully.");
    }
}
```

OUTPUT is
****************SERVER.PORT 10092
Succesfully loaded theenvironment.

Question - **1)** Why is port only from qa profile printed. As dev is also an active profile, I expected port printed for dev and qa as below

****************SERVER.PORT 10091
Succesfully loaded theenvironment.

****************SERVER.PORT 10092
Succesfully loaded theenvironment.

`2)` Is it possible to have two bean created at runtime, one for dev and other for qa ? If so, how can I read bean for qa and for dev?

Answer (score 0):

you could instance your application twice and choose a specific profile for each one ( I think there is no way to start the same application starting in two ports )

You can tell spring to use an specific properties passing the environment in one of ways below:

- Putting `spring.profiles.active=prd` inside application.properties file
- Passing by parameters when start spring app `--spring.profiles.active=dev` ( try config in your IDE for development using )
- Running your jar on command line `java -jar myjar.jar --spring.profiles.active=dev`
- Setting an environment var in your machine/docker/container `SET SPRING_ACTIVES_PROFILE=dev`
- There are other ways using annotations on beans, passing jvm arguments and others

If you need run your tests in a specific configuration ( vars, database, settings ), It's possible to pass which `.properties` will be used

```java
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
@SpringBootTest
@TestPropertySource(locations = "classpath:application-qa.properties")
public class RunTest_from_onlytests_properties {

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;
    
    @Test // org.junit.jupiter.api.Test
    public void test() throws Exception{
      // ...
    }
}
```